# Proving $\mathrm E[XY] = E[X] E[Y]$ whenever $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification, expected-value, independence

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability measure space. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables on it. Then $\mathrm E [XY] = \mathrm E [X] \mathrm E [Y].$

I tried to do it in a measure theoretical way. By definition, we have $$\mathrm E [XY] = \int_{\Omega} X(\omega) Y(\omega)\ \mathrm d \mathbb P(\omega)$$

Consider the random vector $(X,Y) : \Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb R^2$ defined by $\omega \mapsto (X(\omega), Y(\omega)).$ Then for any Borel measurable function $f : \mathbb R^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ we have $$\tag{1}\int\int_{\mathbb R^2} f(x,y)\ \mathrm d \mathbb P_{(X,Y)} (x,y) = \int_{\Omega} f(X(\omega), Y(\omega))\ \mathrm d \mathbb P(\omega)$$ where $\mathbb P_{(X,Y)}$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb R^2$ defined by $\mathbb P_{(X,Y)} (E) = \mathbb P ((X,Y)^{-1} (E)),$ for any $E \in \mathcal B_{\mathbb R^2}.$ Now define $f : \mathbb R^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ by $f(x,y) = xy,\ x, y \in \mathbb R.$ Then $(1)$ becomes $$\int_{\Omega} X(\omega) Y(\omega)\ \mathrm d \mathbb P (\omega) = \int\int_{\mathbb R^2} xy\ \mathrm d \mathbb P_{(X,Y)} (x,y).$$ Now $\mathbb P_{(X,Y)} (A \times B) = \mathbb P (X \in A, Y \in B) = \mathbb P (X \in A) \mathbb P (Y \in B) = \mathbb P_X(A) \mathbb P_Y(B),$ for any $A,B \in \mathcal B_{\mathbb R}.$ From here can we conclude that $\mathbb P_{(X,Y)} = \mathbb P_X \times \mathbb P_Y\ $? For that we need to show that $$\tag{*} \mathbb P_{(X,Y)} (E) = \int\int_{E} \mathrm d \left (\mathbb P_X \times \mathbb P_Y \right ) (x,y)$$ for any $E \in \mathcal B_{\mathbb R^2}.$ I am trying to apply Dynkin $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem here. We consider the collections $\mathcal C : = \left \{A \times B\ |\ A, B \in \mathcal B_{\mathbb R^2} \right \}$ and $\mathcal D : = \left \{E \subseteq \mathbb R^2\ |\ (\ast)\ \text{holds} \right \}.$ Then clearly $\mathcal C$ is a $\pi$-system and $\mathcal D$ is a $\lambda$-system and hence $\mathcal B_{\mathbb R^2} = \sigma (\mathcal C) \subseteq \mathcal D,$ which is what we wanted to show. So we have $$\begin{align*} \mathrm E[XY] & = \left (\int_{\mathbb R} x\ \mathrm d \mathbb P_{X} (x) \right ) \left (\int_{\mathbb R} y\ \mathrm d \mathbb P_{Y} (y) \right ) \\ & = \left (\int_{\Omega} X(\omega)\ \mathrm d \mathbb P (\omega) \right ) \left (\int_{\Omega} Y(\omega)\ \mathrm d \mathbb P (\omega) \right ) \\ & = \mathrm E[X] \mathrm E[Y]. \end{align*}$$

Is my argument fine? Any suggestion for correction or improvement would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Looks good to me. Just another one to think about: First suppose $X,Y\geqslant 0$. Choose an enumeration $(q_0,q_1,\ldots)$ $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,\infty)$ with $q_0=0$. For $n\geqslant 1$, let $0=t_0<t_1<\ldots <t_n$ be an enumeration of $q_0,\ldots, q_n$ in increasing order and let $G_n=\sum_{i=1}^n t_{i-1}1_{\{X\in [t_{i-1},t_i)\}}$. Define $H$ similarly for $Y$. Then $G_n\uparrow X$, $H_n\uparrow Y$, and $G_nH_n\uparrow XY$. Because $G_nH_n$ has products of indicators of one $X$ event and one $Y$ event, independence is easy to apply to get $\mathbb{E}(G_nH_n)=\mathbb{E}(G_n)\mathbb{E}(H_n)$.

Comment: By monotone convergence, $\lim_n \mathbb{E}(G_n)\mathbb{E}(H_n)=\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$, and $\lim_n \mathbb{E}(G_nH_n)=\mathbb{E}(XY)$. But the terms of the limits are equal. 

For the general case split $X=X^+-X^-$, $Y=Y^+-Y^-$. Check that $X^+,X^-$ are each independent of $Y^+,Y^-$ and apply the non-negative case to the four product terms.

Comment: Your way of doing it is the best imo. The really juicy fact is not that $\Bbb E[XY]=\Bbb E[X]\cdot\Bbb E[Y]$, but rather that the associated laws / distributions on $\Bbb R^2$ are equal: $$\mathcal{L}_{(X,Y)}=\mathcal{L}_X\otimes\mathcal{L}_Y$$As an equality of Borel measures

Comment: I think you want to assume that $\mathbb E[X]$ and $\mathbb E[Y]$ exist.

Comment: @RobertIsrael$:$ Yes sir I need to assume that as well. Extremely sorry for that.